# Autostart commands after startup

Tags: raspbian

Please where i have to put my commands, which i need to run after the OS boot up? For example, i need run these commands. (Raspbian OS Bullseye 32bit)
Thanks

```
imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"
xinput --set-prop 12 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
xinput --set-prop 6 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, there are two ways to do this:

1. ***cron:*** Create a `cron` job using the `@reboot` facility; see `man cron` and `man crontab` for details.
2. ***systemd:*** Create a *unit* file to inform `systemd` to start these tasks after (or during) the boot process; see `man systemd` for details. You'll likely need to do some [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+create+systemd+unit+file&atb=v278-1&ia=web) if you're new to `systemd`.

In general: `cron` is easier to set up, while `systemd` gives you much more control at the expense of a steeper learning curve. Feel free to ask follow-on questions once you've chosen an approach.