# Python Script Instead of OS

Tags: boot

I've used Raspbian on the Pi3 to create a Python script (foo.py) which works the way I desire. Now I'd like it to simply boot up and run that python script instead of going into the Raspbian OS (there's no GUI, just GPIO). I can't seem to find this exact use case in previous questions though. Anyone know how to simply launch the script and forego the OS?

Comment: It's not what I wanted, no. Apparently what I wanted was not possible though :-p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the answers to a duplicate question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133551/83790)

`cron` is the simplest:

1. open your `crontab` for editing:

```
crontab -e
```

2. add a job to your crontab by adding a line similar to this:

```
@reboot sleep 15; /path/to/foo.py >> /path/to/mylogfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Was hoping to avoid the OS to make it quicker, but this ultimately does what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to boot an OS in order to run python, you can get Raspbian to run your Python script on boot via cron.

Comment: @Seamus Forego the OS meaning don't use Raspbian. I wanted to stay in a command-prompt type atmosphere. Like when Raspbian doesn't launch appropriately it stays in command-prompt and you can type "startx" to launch it. Kinda thought you could run Python from there.